# try-with-resources initialize to null

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I'm refactoring some old code that looks like this:

```
OutputStreamWriter osw1 = null;
OutputStreamWriter osw2 = null;

try {

    // Some statements...

    if (condition1)
        osw1 = createAnOutputStreamWriter(params1...);

    // Some more statements...

    if (condition2)
        osw2 = createAnOutputStreamWriter(params2...);

    // Some more statements...

} finally {
    try {
        if (osw1 != null)
            osw1.close();
        if (osw2 != null)
            osw2.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore
    }
}
```

I would like to clean up the code, but can't directly replace the outermost `try` use try-with-resources when the variables osw1 and osw2 change to refer to different objects inside the block. Can you offer any suggestions?

Comment: can't put the try-with-resources in each if ?

Comment: Hi, i am looking to do something similar..Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @oggiemc no ideal solution, except maybe azro's suggestion - `if (condition1) try (osw1 = ...)` but this itself can be problematic.